# How to check for enough ventilation for wine cooler

Tags: refrigerator, custom-cabinetry

I have a wine cooler installed in cabinetry with a lower front grille for ventilation. It requires about .5” on each side. I don’t have that space. I have .25” total on the sides. There is about 6” depth in the back, and around 1” on the bottom and .5” on the top. I am trying to make sure I don’t damage the wine cooler. I have bought a temperature controlled outlet. I placed the sensor hanging behind the wine cooler. When the temperature is below 85 degrees F, I keep the power on. If it goes above that temperature, I turn the power off.

This is only temporary to test. I will run the same test with some bottles in there later. For now, I just want to know if this is an accurate way to verify that ventilation is sufficient.

Comment: fill the cooler with bottles of water for the test .... empty fridges use more power

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where does the wine cooler exhaust its heat? Does it have a fan?

Comment: It exhausts in the front. It usually lightly blows hot air.